# Requirejs error - Load timeout for modules: jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have the following folder structure

```
index.html
scripts/
- app.js
- app/
-- main.js
-- page.js
- lib/  
-- require.js
-- jquery.min.js
```

**index.html :**

```
<head>
    <script data-main="scripts/app" src="scripts/lib/require.js"></script>
</head>
```

**app.js :**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts/lib',
    paths: {
        app : '../app',
        jquery : 'jquery.min'
    },
    shim : {
        'jquery': {
            deps : ['app/page'],
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});

requirejs(['app/main']);
```

**main.js :**

```
require(["app/page"], function(page){
    page.renderPage();
});
```

**page.js :**

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    return {
        renderPage : function() {
            //some code
        }
    }
});
```

When index.html is loaded I get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: jquery
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout 
>   at makeError (require.js:168) at checkLoaded (require.js:698) at require.js:719

I have checked a lot of related questions and tried various options but couldn't make jquery work with requirejs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it works if I remove the shim, thank you very much! Do you want to add an answer with an explanation about the relationship between shim and define. I'm not sure I get the point from your comment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have a `shim` for `jquery`. The `shim` configuration option is only for scripts that are not actual AMD modules. An AMD module registers itself with the module loader by calling `define`. jQuery has added support to register itself as an AMD module a long time ago, so it calls `define` itself. You can see it [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/305f193aa57014dc7d8fa0739a3fefd47166cd44/src/exports/amd.js#L21) in its source code:

```
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function() {
        return jQuery;
    } );
}
```

jQuery calls `define` so you must not set a `shim` for it.

There is no defined meaning to using `shim` with AMD modules. In other words, RequireJS does not have to conform to any *specific behavior* when you try to specify a `shim` configuration for an AMD module. RequireJS may just ignore it, or it may behave badly.